# What would be the best way to execute this type of sorting?

Tags: arrays, sorting

The function number_sort takes an integer start, an integer end, an integer skip, and returns an array that has all integers from start to end, excluding integers with the digit skip in it

```js
function number_sort(start, end, skip){
}
```

Expected Output

number_sort (1, 20, 1) → [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20]

1 was skipped,
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, and 19 were also skipped because they contain the digit 1!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Usually people do not like the subjective questions of what is the best way to do something. What have you tried so far/What has not worked? Also, what program are you writing this in? R? Python?

Comment: In what way is this *sorting*?

Comment: What language is this to be written in?  Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving it yourself?

Comment: Depends on many things. Is speed of sorting important? Is memory usage important? What language are you using? Have you tried something already and aren't happy with it and why ?

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong but assumed that you're using JavaScript to solve this problem. I'll try to explain solution so you could rewrite it to whatever technology you're using. 
The easiest possible thing to generate numbers is of course for loop. As an argument you have first number to generate and the last one. Just increment it and here you go - you got numbers generated from 1 to 20 (in example you've provided).
Next thing - condition. Skip numbers that contain *skip* parameter. Pretty easy too. I don't know if there's more effective way than just casting generated number to string and checking if it contains this *skip* parameter. If not - add it to your results array. And that's it.

```
function number_sort(start, end, skip){
var result = [];
for (i = start; i <= end; i++) {
  if (!i.toString().contains(skip)) result.push(i);
 }
 return result;
}
```

BTW It's not sorting - it's just generating array of numbers meeting some kind of condition.